# CakePHP - Are these files unnecessary?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

When you download CakePHP, these files are present:

.editorconfig, .travis.yml, build.properties, and build.xml

I have never really had to edit these files before or use them for my applications, but I never deleted them. Are these files important? Or can I just delete them?

I am using CakePHP version 2.4.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### You can delete them

The files do serve a purpose but they are not used by the application at run time.

### What are they for

- [.editorconfig](http://editorconfig.org/) is a file used to help ensure code is consistently formatted.
- [.travis.yml](http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/build-configuration/) is a file used to configure automated builds using [travis](https://travis-ci.org/cakephp/cakephp) - so that the test suite runs automatically for commits and pull requests.
- [build.xml](http://www.phing.info/docs/guide/stable/ch04s02.html) is used to create a new release, and update [pear](http://pear.cakephp.org/) using [phing](http://www.phing.info/).
- [build.properties](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.4.2/build.xml#L21) is a configuration file containing info used by phing (see above) to parameters [pirum](http://pirum.sensiolabs.org/) - to update the cakephp pear channel.